# Numpy dot issue

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm using the dot function from NumPy to perform a matrix-matrix multiplication.

If I understand correctly matrix multiplication, all the following methods should give exactly the same output:

```
print(L.dot(Linv)[3,9]) # 1.6335244394160178
print((L @ Linv)[3,9]) # 1.6335244394160178
print(np.einsum("ab,bc->ac", L, Linv)[3,9]) # 0.0
print(np.sum(L[3,:] * Linv[:, 9])) # 0.0
```

However, I get different outputs. What are the @ and the dot function of numpy doing exactly? In the guide, it is stated that if the arguments are matrices, then matrix multiplication is performed.

I add here the incipit of the script to reproduce the results (the L and Linv data):

```
import numpy as np



# Here the data (to avoid providing them as separate files)
L = """4.479724067043496655e-03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 7.575031573076805927e-03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 8.064946672744280343e-03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.791889624443217602e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.583779244138073083e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 2.370534380663733703e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 4.660235266606813781e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 2.456610752804347375e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 4.808574715302278701e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.030012629223697435e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 6.060025258433345691e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.127228142619950524e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 6.252921272151366894e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.225978669094593798e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 6.451957338182952306e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.187090592571762969e-11 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 2.374181060083024875e-11 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 7.731783473260393920e-12 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 4.041674736032681292e-04 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 7.969768304550615905e-12 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 5.232339515320802437e-04 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.512224603796989392e-14 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 7.024762715968080329e-14 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 2.567506045249735244e-14 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 7.675065442667300397e-06 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.559086410488709934e-14 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.117991975720713071e-14
"""

Linv = """
2.232280348150939915e+02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.320126510830928055e+02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.239933803132919365e+02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -1.086791229124879599e+09 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.640489815681053184e+18 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 4.218458275757972586e+01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -4.864074749046730176e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 4.070649078911282004e+01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -3.740969059520440624e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 7.394997851743471110e+05 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -6.379414590867070720e+17 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.197720028993738950e+01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -2.605201446299405361e+05 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -5.344491450056607137e+05 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.105917882360113408e+18
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 5.433956431859214306e+08 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -8.202449089273177600e+17 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -8.069972996184295637e-07 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 2.474221957280944935e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -6.200310571028803009e-07 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.911191020549333189e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -3.697333910066453391e+05 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.189707295440930560e+17 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -1.069719283410347248e-07 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.302920495152602234e+05 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 2.672400716756277252e+05 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -5.529589411805911040e+17
"""



# Write the data
fp = open("_L_", "w")
fp.write(L)
fp.close()

fp = open("_Linv_", "w")
fp.write(Linv)
fp.close()


# Load them as numpy array
L = np.loadtxt("_L_")
Linv = np.loadtxt("_Linv_")


print(L.dot(Linv)[3,9]) # 1.6335244394160178
print((L @ Linv)[3,9]) # 1.6335244394160178
print(np.einsum("ab,bc->ac", L, Linv)[3,9]) # 0.0
print(np.sum(L[3,:] * Linv[:, 9])) # 0.0
```

EDIT:

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, using Anaconda and python 3.8.5 (GCC 7.3.0), numpy 1.19.2:

The result of `np.show_config()` is

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/darth-vader/anaconda3/include']
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? What does `np.show_config()` show?

Comment: @Eric 
I added the details in the answer of my python version.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the issue,
There is nothing wrong with the text or the python installation, but it is a problem of the matrix itself.
By replacing

```
# Write the data
fp = open("_L_", "w")
fp.write(L)
fp.close()

fp = open("_Linv_", "w")
fp.write(Linv)
fp.close()


# Load them as numpy array
L = np.loadtxt("_L_")
Linv = np.loadtxt("_Linv_")
```

With:

```
L = np.genfromtxt(L.splitlines(), dtype = np.float128)
Linv = np.genfromtxt(Linv.splitlines(), dtype = np.float128)
```

The problem is solved (both give the same result, different from what obtained with double precision). The fact is that the Linv has elements that are as big as 1e17, the limit of numerical accuracy of double precision.
Therefore, if the row-by-column matrix multiplication is performed by summing elements in different order, the truncation error will act differently. This is the reason why np.dot and matmul gives a different result from einsum and sum.

The reason why in some numpy version it does not I think may depend on the configuration of blas, lapack and mkl, that may change the behavior of dot and matmul functions.

Answer (score 0):

With you sample arrays (copy and paste a strings works fine):

```
In [86]: X=np.genfromtxt(L.splitlines())
In [87]: Y=np.genfromtxt(Linv.splitlines())
In [88]: X.shape
Out[88]: (15, 15)
In [89]: (X@Y).shape
Out[89]: (15, 15)
```

I get 0 for all the [3,9] elements

```
In [90]: np.allclose(X.dot(Y),X@Y)
Out[90]: True
In [91]: np.allclose(X.dot(Y),np.einsum('ab,bc->ac',X,Y))
Out[91]: True
In [92]: (X@Y)[3,9]
Out[92]: 0.0
```

Comment: that is really wired. I tried updating to the last version of numpy with anaconda, but it still gives me the wrong answer (allclose between dot and einsum results False to me, with dot that gives the wrong result, the shapes are correct). Does it exist a numpy test-suite to check if everything is working correctly?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with you python/numpy istallation.  There's something about your arrays that the text version doesn't convey.  Have you tested that code in a new python session?  My machine runs a straight forward linux/pip installation.

Comment: I think this is because I have the anaconda version of numpy, installed with MKL libraries. In this way, the dot function of numpy is implemented differently to exploit multiprocessing, that is why our results differ.